# RVO and deleted move constructor in C++14

Tags: c++, c++14, move-constructor

I have been learning about (N)RVO for a last few days. As I read on cppreference in the copy elision article, for C++14 :

> ... the compilers are permitted, but not required to omit the copy- and move- (since C++11)construction of class objects even if the copy/move (since C++11) constructor and the destructor have observable side-effects. This is an optimization: even when it takes place and the **copy-/move-constructor** is not called, it still **must be present and accessible** (as if no optimization happened at all), otherwise the program is ill-formed.

So, either copy **or** move constructor must be present and accessible. But in the code bellow:

```
#include <iostream>

class myClass
{
public:
    myClass() { std::cout << "Constructor" << std::endl; }
    ~myClass() { std::cout << "Destructor" << std::endl; }

    myClass(myClass const&) { std::cout << "COPY constructor" << std::endl;}
    myClass(myClass &&) = delete;
};

myClass foo()
{
    return myClass{};
}

int main()
{
    myClass m = foo();
    return 0;
}
```

I got the following error: `test.cpp: In function 'myClass foo()':
test.cpp:15:17: error: use of deleted function 'myClass::myClass(myClass&&)'
  return myClass{};`. I get this error even if I don't call `foo()` from the `main()`. The same issue with NRVO.

Hence the move constructor is always required, isn't it? (while the copy is not, I checked it)

I do not understand where compiler needs a move constructor. My only guess is that it might be required for constructing a temporary variable, but it sounds doubtful. Do someone knows an answer?

About the compiler: I tried it on g++ and VS compilers, you can check it online:  http://rextester.com/HFT30137.

P.S. I know that in C++17 standard the RVO is obligated. But the NRVO isn't, so I want to study out what is going on here to understand when I can use NRVO.

Comment: Compiles as C++ 17 with gcc 7.2

Comment: Rule of thumb: Never explicitly delete move operations. Instead define or delete the copy operations explicitly, which suppresses generation of moves. The only case in which explicitly deleting move operations makes a difference is this one in which you end up with a pathological copyable-but-not-movable type.

Comment: @Casey, so, the only case, when it is ok to delete a move operator, it is when you delete both copy and move? Or in this case deleting a move operator is unnecessarily?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cited from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Deleted_functions):

> Deleted functions
>
> If, instead of a function body, the special syntax = delete ; is used, the function is defined as deleted.
>
> ...
>
> **If the function is overloaded, overload resolution takes place first, and the program is only ill-formed if the deleted function was selected.**

It's not the same thing if you explicitly define the move constructor to be deleted. Here because of the presence of this deleted move constructor, although the copy constructor can match, the move constructor is better, thus the move constructor is selected during overload resolution.

If you remove the explicit `delete`, then the copy constructor will be selected and your program will compile.

Comment: Good answer, but I recommend an edit to beat home the point that even though the Copy constructor is there and good, the move constructor is a better fit and is selected over the copy constructor.

Comment: Thanks. I used to write explicit `delete` in aim to forbid use the default constructor. As I understand now if I have defined a copy constructor the default move constructor would not be created. Is it?

Comment: @user4581301 There is a user-declared copy-constructor, so the move constructor is not implicitly declared, so the copy-constructor will be called.

Comment: @user4581301 Answer updated with simple explanation. In fact here the return value is an rvalue, the result is easy to predict. But even if in OP's function an lvalue is returned, it's still the move-constructor to be selected. Maybe it's too lengthy to quote all these material to the answer.

Comment: @AnyaMitrushchienkova Yes, compiler won't generate it.

Comment: @liliscent Cool, I didn't know it. I heard a rule that if you defined a copy constructor, you should also define a copy assignment operator and destructor. I thought it also true for move operators.

Comment: @AnyaMitrushchienkova you write of the Rule of Three. There are two other rules, the aptly named Rules of Five and Zero, which cover the rest of the bases. [Here is a link to a discussion of all three rules and how they relate.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)